# After windows server 2019 update- my domain is not reachable any more

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2019, xampp

well as I do not know where is the problem, I will explain every thing. And as I do not have any experience with server managing, I will show some screenshots and please help and if you have an answer please try to say it as simple as possible.

I have a website built with CodeIgniter and Xampp as webserver. And a server which host the directory project. So on the server the xampp host the project localhost und it will be directed to the domain. It has worked very well but after an update the domain is not any more reachable. I think this may be due to the fact that the server settings or xampp setting have to be adjusted. Xampp has no error. When I try to ping my domain on the server I become the error: Reply From < IP address >: Destination Host Unreachable When I try to ping my domain on an external device I become the error: Request timed out
Here are some screenshots
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65892549/server-problem-after-windows-server-2019-update-my-domain-is-not-reachable-any